# SignalR, dashboard and getting data from workers in multiple data centers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I'm trying to understand if the following scenario is supported and if so, what's the best way to implement this:

I have a number of worker roles that perform work in different data centers (Azure).  The servers within the data centers are the same and perform similar type of work for a large number of customers.

I have a dashboard that should show up to date data from results generated by workers within all of the data centers.  A customer can and will have data from multiple data centers.

I would prefer to not have direct connection from my dashboard to worker roles

I understand that one can use Worker roles as SignalR clients and send information to my Web API servers that are SignalR servers.. HOWEVER, my worker roles maybe processing data for 1000 customers, while only 2 or 3 of them are online and viewing the dashboard.  I do not want to burden my worker roles by sending data from multiple data centers for every customer they're processing if only 2/3 of them are online and waiting for the data.  Also, there are data transfer costs that I'd like to avoid.

So, is it possible for me to send data from my remote worker roles to my centralized dashboard only for customers who are online and are viewing the dashboards?

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that setting up the worker roles as SignalR clients, may not be the most performant solution. Since all of this is taking place within Azure data centers, you might as well make use of some tools they offer. [Azure Queues](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) might work for you. Your worker roles can put messages in the queue, and then the SignalR hub can receive these messages as you want. You could for example track if anyone is connected to the hub, and only then listen to messages from the queue. [This excellent](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Queues-101-Basics-of-Queues-with-Mark-Simms) video can give you a great introduction to queues.